# Viewing output contained in slurm.out file

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm

I have a C++ program that when run on my local machine runs some simulations and saves the results in a .csv file.

I am now running the same program on a cluster. Jobs are scheduled with SLURM, queued, and then run to completion. Rather than a .csv file output, the output is a slurmid.out file. How can I access this file to see the results of my simulation?

Comment: I always use `less` to view any file, it keeps my terminal clean and makes the file contents scrollable.

Answer (score 1):

I typically use the cat command to view slurm output files-

> cat slurmid.out

You could also use vim,  or any other text editor/viewer. The script should probably output the csv file as well- If its not because it's failing, the .out file will tell you about it.